# Nginx and uWSGI (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream

Tags: nginx, uwsgi

I'm trying to deploy my Flask app with Nginx and uWSGI.

This is the conf:

```
server {
     listen 6543;
     
     location / {
              include uwsgi_params;
              uwsgi_pass unix:/home/developer/spir-back-end/spir-back-end.sock
     }
}
```

This is the spir-back-end.ini file inside the project:

```
[uwsgi]
module = wsgi:app

master = true
processes = 4

chmod-socket = 660
vaccum = true

die-on-term = true
```

This is spir-back-end.service:

```
[Unit]
Description=uWSGI instance to serve spir-back-end
After=network.target

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/home/developer/spir-back-end
Environment="PATH=/home/developer/spir-back-end/backendvenv/bin"
ExecStart=/home/developer/spir-back-end/backendvenv/bin/uwsgi --ini spir-back-end.ini

[Install]
WantedBy=multi.user.target
```

When I try to reach the page, I get 502 Bad Gateway.

I looked into error.log file and I saw that the error is:

```
*16 connect() to unix:/home/developer/spir-back-end/spir-back-end.sock failed (13 Permission denied) while connecting to upstream
```

I specify I did not create a `.socket` file to insert into `spir-back-end.ini` file.

Comment: Check what is the file permission on `/home/developer/spir-back-end/spir-back-end.sock` and check what user is nginx running on make sure the right user in `uwsgi` config

Comment: I checked, file permssion on  `.sock` file is `srw-rw---- 1 root root`. Also `root` is running nginx. How you can see, I did not define any user in `uwsgi` config, should I define `User=root` ?